# Google Map Marker

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I created a website where different locations are shown per user's search. Those locations are identified by their postcodes which I previously added them in a Database. However, I would like to add Google map with markers on those locations. My plan is when the user clicks for a particular location's details, a map will pop up with the marker. So I used codes for Google map, the problem is I had to specify lat & long to get the marker. I want a code that will dynamically get those locations postcodes and marker for each.
Note: I used this code to get the map.

```
<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850); //I don't want this value fixed
var marker;

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:5,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And this was used in view.aspx to display postcodes from database:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostCode) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use search API to get lat and lng from post code :

1) Add this script to header :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

2) Use this JavaScript function to get lat,lng by postcode :

```
function GetLocation() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
                } else {
                    alert("Request failed.")
                }
            });
        };
```

3) Then you can use your code to pass lat and lng values